# Acumatica Error when publishing a customization: conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime

Tags: acumatica

Does somebody know how to solve: "conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value" when I try to publish a customization in Acumatica 6.10? Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the data type of a field in one of the tables was changed. The publishing process is not going to know how to change the value. compared the tables used in your customization to their current types in SQL.

Also, you might be trying to convert a value where the current value does not fit into the new type. For example a converted string value of "15 Jan 2117" would fail to convert to SQL SmallDateTime as the max date is "6 Jun 2079"

Either way you best friend here might be to run a SQL profiler to find the table/sql syntax trying to execute.

**Edit:** If you change the field in SQL you must reset the app in IIS as it caches the table structure when the site first loads. After you make the SQL change do this and then update your customization project database table/script by clicking RELOAD FROM DATABASE. Then when you publish it will be using the correct data type.

Comment: Yesterday I executed a change in SQL server. I stablished the default language to english and customization could published. I don't know if there is something weird in the way acumatica sends the information to SQL

Comment: I updated the answer. Basically you have to reset your site if you are making changes in SQL for the site to see the table changes.